# how to recreate CURL command in Powershell or HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, powershell, curl, httpwebrequest

I have curl command, how execute it on PowerShell?

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime" -k --cert C:\certnew.cer --key C:\private.key --pass 123123 --request POST "mysite.com" --data "RequestBodyTemplate"
```

I could not find in PowerShell how to sign a request with two certificates

```
--cert C:\certnew.cer --key C:\private.key --pass 123123
```

It's my powershell script, and it's not works!

```
$certPath = "C:\certnew.cer"
$keyPath = "C:\private.key"
$keyPass = "123123"
$url = "https://localhost.com:80/webservice"
$data = "-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
         MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCA
         JIAEgYY8P3htbCB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjAiIGVuY29kaW5nPSJVVEYtOCI/Pg0KPHRl
         -----END PKCS7-----"

$CURLEXE = 'C:\curl\bin\curl.exe'
$CurlArgument = '-v', '-H', 'Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime',
                '-k', '--cert', $certPath,
                '--key', $keyPath, '--pass', $keyPass
                '--request', 'POST', "$url",
                '--data', $data
& $CURLEXE @CurlArgument
```

I get an error:

```
curl.exe : curl: no URL specified!
```

Comment: Within `$CurlArgument` you're missing a comma after `$keyPass` so the next two lines aren't being included. Secondly you're trying to splat an array to curl `@CurlArgument` this isn't going to work (splatting uses hashtable and curl won't accept one anyway). Instead try `& $CURLEXE $CurlArgument`

Comment: Yes, inattention. But now another mistake: _curl.exe : Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred._

Comment: Top comment is not actual.

Comment: You don't need to use `--request POST` alongside `-d`/`--data` as it's already inferred when using it. Reading the documentation for curl might help you as it explains this.